# xml insertion using loadrunner script

Tags: xml, insertion, loadrunner

here I am using LoadRunner 11.52. I am trying to insert multiple attribute in xml(web http protocol). So when I add 1 attribute it works perfectly fine but whn I add multiple attribute output comes unwanted characters.

ex: xml->

Code: `lr_xml_insert("Xml=UsedAboveXML",
    "Query=/a/b/c",
        "ResultParam=Result2",
        "Position=attribute",
        "XmlFragment=authorizedAmtmt=\"0\" unused1=\"0\"",
        LAST);`

Desired Output: `<a><b><c authorizedAmtmt="0" unused1="0"></c></b></a>`

Actual Output: `<a><b><c authorizedAmtmt="0&quot; unused1=&quot;0"></c></b></a>`

What is the mistake I am doing. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?   Here is the route I would go:

- Double escape the intermediary quotes
- Move to a sprintf() model for building your XML stream.

My best guess is that this is likely a by design issue.  If you notice all of the intermediary quote symbols have been replaced with the embedded quote placeholder for the XML (quotes inside of quotes vs quotes that end a value.    But, as this is C, you should have several alternate paths to build your XML string, up to and including developing your own API for manipulation.

Comment: I tried Double Escape,it didnt work, see the alt solution is I am inserting all the attribute and at the end I am using a replace function to replace "&quot;" by "". But I wanted to know whether there is any solution we can provide inline to lr_xml_insert() to avoid extra efforts.